# Como configurar o tomcat no windows 7?

Tags: java, tomcat

Como configurar o Tomcat 7 no windows 7?

É preciso configurar variáveis de ambiente do java?

Answer (score 1):

**Programador antigo**,

Para configurar o Tomcat em ambiente windows siga estes passos:

[Download](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) do Tomcat 7

[Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) do Java+ JDK(se você vai desenvolver)

**Configuração Java**

A instalação do Java não tem muito segredo, escolha o local desejado e faça a instalação do mesmo. Após o termino é necessário indicar onde ele está instalado para o windows :

> Meu computador > propriedades > configurações avançadas do sistema >
>   variáveis de ambiente > novo :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nome da variável : JAVA_HOME

Valor da variável: O caminho onde está instalado.

**Configuração Tomcat**

Geralmente para meus testes instalo como serviço no windows, mas se preferir apenas descompacte o arquivo e coloco onde desejar. Escolha as portas que o tomcat ira usar, o padrão geralmente é 8080 mas você pode alterar isso no tomcat manager.

O Tomcat também precisa ser colocado nas variaveis de ambiente, siga os mesmos passos até chegar em variáveis de ambiente e clique em novo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nome da variável: CATALINA_HOME

Valor da variável: caminho para a pasta do tomcat7

Com isso seu Tomcat já pode rodar normalmente no ambiente windows, lembrando que a configuração é a mesma para windows `xp,vista,7,8 e 8.1`

Comment: que dificíl, quanta configuração, não tem algum .msi que dê um clique e o serviço já fica rodando ? Vou continuar com o tomcat no linux mesmo então rssrsrsr

Comment: @SneepSNinjA, não tem segredo na configuração, no máximo em 10 minutos você está codando.